# Making decision depending on complicated factors without starting data

Tags: neural-network, data-analysis, reinforcement-learning

Currently I'm building an automatically making decision system, which depends on many different factors. The problems I meet that is don't have any data to analyze and train.

My system has some factors, such as is on Holiday or not, is on Maintenance Status or not, Currently Connected Users (CCU), etc. But from beginning I have to collect data and analyze on realtime (each 5 minutes my system will send data to me).

I'm looking for a Machine Learning approach to solve this problems. Because I don't have any ideas for set ratio of each factors in order to make decision. I am reading about Reinforcement Learning, that it can make decision, and will reward/punish it on Accept/Decline the decision. But I can't find any ideas of using this approach on solving the problem.

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? You either should introduce a concrete rules on how to make the decisions and cover all the possible combinations, or collect training set to feed your learning algorithms.